# what is meant by that ASP.NET VNext is cloud optimized?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have recently started doing Research and Development on ASP.NET vNext and I am trying to understand following:

1. How is ASP.NET MVC vNext cloud optimized?
2. What are major changes to the .NET Core, .NET 4.6 that ASP.NET MVC vNext are called cloud optimized?
3. What is meant by the fact that ASP.NET MVC, Web API and Web Pages now share a unified core? Whats the advantage of that?

Kindly help me understanding these concepts from a beginners point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vNext apps can use a cloud-optimized subset of the .NET framework. This subset of the framework is about 11 megabytes in size compared to 200 megabytes for the full framework, and is composed of a collection of NuGet packages.
It is not required that you use this subset of the framework you can still use the full framework depending on what parts of the framework your application needs. 
Previously there was a moderate amount of duplicate concepts between MVC and WebApi.  The routing systems and framework extension points where very similar but different implementations.  They are now the same framework. You can return MVC and WebApi results in the same controller if you want. Web Pages will be added to MVC 6 in a later release.

> ASP.NET 5 (Panel Discussion)
>   http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/023
>
> Five Essential Things to know about ASP.NET vNext (David Fowler Damian Edwards)
>   https://vimeo.com/113688715
>
> ASP.NET vNext 101 (Damian Edwards, David Fowler)
>   http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2014/ASP-NET-vNext-101

The .Net Core is a subset of the .Net framework similar to the BCL that has been open sourced and is supported by Microsoft on Windows, Linux and Mac OSX

> Introducing .NET Core
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx

Edit: New Video from NDC confrence on June 19, 2015

> What’s new in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 - Jon Galloway and Damian Edwards
>   https://vimeo.com/131199086

Comment: So you mean that the cloud optimization is simply the fact that it uses a lighter Framework ? So if I understand correctly it is meant to be a good thing because it will reduce the ressources you use and thus your bill, right ?

Comment: They are also removing the dependency on System.Web.  Currently just initializing the request via System.Web is I believe 100k of memory and that will go down to 10k per request.  They are also getting rid of the .csproj file which has been a source of pain when merging it into source control (git, tfs etc..)

Comment: woaoh !!! thats some awesome news ! ... 
Thanks for the detailed info @NathanSmith :)

Comment: How do you know they will add web pages?

Comment: First this post is five months old so many things have changed as many more things will change before ASP.NET 5 RTM.  There are many blog post out there that reference the "Web Pages" project format as being planned for ASP.NET 5. https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5  Currently in ASP.NET 4 you create a "Web Pages" project with (File>New>Web Site) vs (File>New>Project) for MVC projects.  Personally I use the MVC project format not "Web Pages" so I really don't know that much about it.